# PHP syntax for autoincrement parent array

Tags: php, html, forms, server-side, server-side-rendering

```
<input name=foo[]>
<input name=foo[]>
<input name=foo[][]><input name=foo[][]><input name=foo[][]>
<input name=foo[]>
```

`$_POST['foo']` is not created as `array('1st', '2nd', array('3rd', '4th', '5th'), '6th')`.

In order to do so I'll have to put in the index for the child array:

```
<input name=foo[]>
<input name=foo[]>
<input name=foo[2][]><input name=foo[2][]><input name=foo[2][]>
<input name=foo[]>
```

This however is less neat (especially for pages running huge indexes).

Is there a neater syntax to solve the problem?

Perhaps a syntax that can refer to the latest index for that array level?

For example, if the underscore character would do so, then instead of keeping track of ugly $i variables it could be as simple as this:

```
<input lorem name=foo[]>   lo 
<input ipsum name=foo[][]> re <input jhuin name=foo[_][]><input velit name=foo[_][]>
<input neque name=foo[]>   mi
<input porro name=foo[]>   ps
<input situn name=foo[]>   um
<input quiar name=foo[]>   jh
<input dolor name=foo[][]> ui <input adipi name=foo[_][]>
<input conse name=foo[]>   nv
```

..and even:

```
<input lorem name=foo[]> lo
<input ipsum name=foo[]> re
<input jhuin name=foo[][]><input velit name=foo[_][]><input neque name=foo[_][]>
                         mi                          <input porro name=foo[_][_][]>
                         ps                          <input situn name=foo[_][_][]>
                         um                          <input quiar name=foo[_][_][]>
                         jh                          <input dolor name=foo[_][_][]>
<input conse name=foo[]> ui
<input adipi name=foo[]> nv
<input yaruk name=foo[]> el
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible directly. One option is to serialize the form data using JSON, then you can send JSON data to the server if you prefer. An example implementation is Jquery plugin `serializeJSON` (no built-in conversion)

```
var data=$("form").serializeJSON();
```

Even you can convert back to a regular querystring (with added indexes) for POST or GET

```
var queryString = $.param(data);
```

Now the queryString is indexed as expected.

```js
$(function(){
  
  var data=$("form").serializeJSON();
  console.log(data);  
  var newQueryString = $.param(data);
  console.log(newQueryString);        
  $("body").append($("<pre></pre>").text(JSON.stringify(data,null,"  ")));
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.serializeJSON/2.9.0/jquery.serializejson.js"></script>
<form method="POST">
<input name=foo[] value=1>
<input name=foo[] value=2>
<input name=foo[][]  value=3><input name=foo[][]  value=4><input name=foo[][] value=5>
     <input name=foo[][][] value=6>
     <input name=foo[][][] value=7>
     <input name=foo[][][] value=8>
     <input name=foo[][][] value=9>
<input name=foo[] value=10>
<input name=foo[] value=11>
<input name=foo[] value=12>
  <input type="submit" value=Submit>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to give the index a value in order to create array like  `array('first', array('second', 'third', 'fourth'), 'fifth')`.

there is no way around. Doing like foo[] will automatically give index to the array.
this is shortcut for array_push.
foo[] in input roughly means push the value of input in variable name foo and as you know push will always append value at the end.